# Which Kindle Paperwhite model/generation do I have?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I need to determine which firmware update to download. The Amazon site is helpful if you know exactly which generation or model of Kindle you have. But they give no guidance as to how to determine which generation or model I own.

Is there some way on the hardware or within the software to determine which generation of Kindle Paperwhite I have?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While impossible for me to find on my own, an external link brought me to this page by Amazon with hints as to how to identify which of the many Kindle models you may have:

- [Which Kindle E-reader do I have?](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=201263790)

From the blog post, [How to Tell Kindle Paperwhite Generations Apart](https://blog.the-ebook-reader.com/2015/07/01/how-to-tell-kindle-paperwhite-generations-apart/), I learned this:

- The first Paperwhite has big “Kindle” logo on back, versus “Amazon” for the 2nd and 3rd Paperwhites.
- The 2nd generation of Paperwhite has a light “Kindle” logo on front versus the 3rd generation that has a blacked-out “Kindle” logo on the front.

### Generations

- The first generation of Paperwhite is also known as “Kindle 5th Generation”. ([firmware updates - archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114055717/https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201064850))
- Second is “Kindle 6th Generation”. ([firmware updates - archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20180309144011/http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_cn?nodeId=201307450))
- Third is “Kindle 7th Generation”. ([firmware updates - archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20161016000047/https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201756220))

### Flowchart

I distilled the information from the articles linked above into this flowchart.

[image: Kindle Paperwhite flow chart]

[image: Kindle Paperwhite serial numbers]

Comment: Can be more clear if you can add screenshot of those logos.

Comment: The logos are physical part of case, hardware, not software on screen.

Comment: There is also Amazon's [Identify your Kindle e-reader](https://www.amazonforum.com/s/identify-your-kindle-e-reader) which surprisingly is more detailed than the already referenced Amazon link. For example, it includes serial number prefixes. However those aren't necessarily complete, e.g. looked up a 6th gen Kindle and its serial number didn't match any of the listed prefixes.

Comment: In settings you should be able to find the serial number of your device. Then you should be able to lookup the exact version here: https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_Serial_Numbers

Comment: download links in your great answer are broken, ie second version updates are at https://www.amazon.com/update_Kindle_Paperwhite_6th_Gen per https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GKMQC26VQQMM8XSW