# Can I turn on a non responding Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, battery

According to [this answer](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/6616/11499) it's 2nd generation, and no matter how much I charge I always get the following screen, can anything be done?

[image: Battery not charging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow [Amazon's forum](https://www.amazonforum.com/s/question/0D54P00007FrRkD/how-to-start-kindle-displaying-a-battery-symbol-with-exclamation-mark) by pressing and holding the power button until the screen went blank. Then I clicked it again for about a minute. It didn't help.

But after a few days of no charge, I just clicked the button to turn it on, and it did! Guess it needed some time off...so if it happens to you, have patience and try this before you throw away the device.